# Is there a way to return an array of structs in Solidity without de-structuring the fields?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I've been doing some research around this issue, but I couldn't find a definite answer. I'm using solidity 0.4.24.

I have a contract like this:

```
contract {
    struct FutureOperation is Ownable {
        uint256 date;
        uint256 price;
        uint256 amount;
        string name;
    }

    FutureOperation[] futureOperations;

    // ...

    function getAllFutureOperations() public onlyOwner returns (FutureOperation[]) {
        return futureOperations;
    }
}
```

When I compile this in Remix I get the following error:

```
browser/myfuturetoken.sol:53:64: TypeError: This type is only supported in the new experimental ABI encoder. Use "pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;" to enable the feature.
```

I found some blog posts saying that I should de-structure the fields in the struct to return them as arrays of the primitive types. So, in this case, it would look something like this:

```
function getAllFutureOperations() public onlyOwner returns (uint256[] dates, uint256[] prices, uint256[] amounts, string[] names) {
        return futureOperations;
    }
```

Is there an alternative for that? Are the newer compilers capable of returning an array of structs?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As error stated, returning dynamic array is not supported by compiler yet. However, experiment feature supported it. To use experimental compiler, you need to make some changes as follows,

```
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract myContract{

    struct FutureOperation {
        uint256 date;
        uint256 price;
        uint256 amount;
        string name;
    }

    string[] futureOperations;

    function getAllFutureOperations() public view returns (string[] memory) {
        return futureOperations;
    }

}
```

*Note: make sure to not use experimental things in production version*

Comment: Why is futureOperations an array of string? How does the compiler know that futureOperations is an array of FutureOperation?